# Would it be possible to reword this instance of “préferer quelqu'un à quelqu'un d'autre”?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, pronoms

I'm reading *Le Rouge et le Noir* and I've found the next sentence:

> Ah! Si j'eusse été ainsi, elle ne m'eût pas préféré Croisenois!

I understand that it can be translated as:

> Ah! If I would have been like this she wouldn't have preferred Croisenois over me.

But I would have expressed this as:

> Ah! Si j'eusse été ainsi, elle n'eût pas préféré Croisenois à moi!

Would that be correct? In case it is, is the first way of writing it preferable? Why is it so?

Comment: "Ah! Si j'eusse été ainsi, elle ne m'eût pas préféré Croisenois!" is very formal (and old fashionned)

Comment: Also, remember that you should put a (non-breaking) space before "!", "?", ";", ":" in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your re-phrasing is absolutely correct. But much less 1830-ish, so to speak.

The first way of writing is just an old-school way of speaking, but your understanding is very good.

Comment: I don't know, modernising the sentence gives me "Si j'avais ressemblé à ça, elle m'aurait pas préféré Croisenois", with a weak pronoun still. Using a strong pronoun instead sounds like child-speak to my ears. (I feel like we'd use another expression altogether to avoid that difficulty though)

Comment: "Si j'avais ressemblé à ça, elle NE m'aurait pas préféré Croisenois"* ;)

Comment: Sans oublier le "Ah !".